# Declare multiple variables in php script to save space

Tags: php, forms, variables

I have a huge form and am declaring all these variables ...

```
$MaidenName= $_POST['MaidenName'];
$PhoneHome= $_POST['PhoneHome'];
$SSN= $_POST['SSN'];
$BirthPlace= $_POST['BirthPlace'];
$DOB= $_POST['DOB'];
$Email= $_POST['Email'];
$MaritalStatus= $_POST['MaritalStatus'];  +many more...
```

I was hoping I could maybe declare them on the same line just to save space in the script with maybe a comma but that wont work ... is there another way?

Comment: Don't do that.  It's harder to read and maintain.  Keep them on multiple, separate lines. By the way, you might want to check out [extract()](http://us2.php.net/extract) - in this case, would be `extract($_POST)`.  (Remember to sanitize your input!).  Also, there are many coding style guides worth checking out, that give you some "best practices" for formatting code.  Example: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html

Comment: There is no point minifying your code. It makes the readibility worse + almost none performance gain. 1 Expression per line.

Comment: The parser parses the string into individual sections which separated by ";" in the first case. As the parser reads line by line, you should if possible have only one statement per line. Especially in some 1000 lines relieves the parser noticeably.

Comment: @cale_b: It's really not recommended to use `extract()` on untrusted data, in this case on `$_POST`.

Comment: @rocknrollcanneverdie - True. Hence my follow-up comment to **be sure to sanitize your input**....

Comment: I thought prepared statements were supposed to make this safer.

Comment: You could also do a `foreach` on the `$_POST`. Then you've very clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing this as you were selecting the other answer, but here it is anyway:

```
$item = array('MaidenName', 'PhoneHome', 'SSN', 'BirthPlace', 'DOB', 'Email', 'MaritalStatus');

foreach ($item as $key => $value)
{
    $key = $value;
    echo $key . "\n"; // this line is just for testing
    $_POST['$value'];
}
```

it's a more professional way of doing it.

Comment: A more professional way of doing that by setting `$key = $value`? uhuh.. Your whole `foreach` makes no sense with `$key => $value`. It is not a 2 dimensional array!

Comment: He wants to set his $_POST up as `$var = $_POST['$var'];` — this accomplishes that.

Comment: Why would you use `$key => $value` instead of just `$value`? See my PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/esv-5am

Comment: I've read that, but why would you print that for testing? What's the value of that line? And just relax, that would make life a bit easier for you hehe

Answer (score 1):

I see there is an accepted answer, but still want to share a "foreachless" way:

```
extract(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(['a','b','c'])));
```

This will create $a, $b and $c vars from $_POST, ignoring all of the other keys

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array. Here is an example:

```
<?php
    $array = array("favfruit"=>"apple","favcar"=>"ford","favgal"=>"sally","favsite"=>"stackoverflow");
    print $array['favfruit'];
?>
```

Or for your instance:

```
<?php
    $personaldetails = array("MaidenName"=>$_POST['MaidenName'],"PhoneHome"=>$_POST['PhoneHome'],"SSN"=>$_POST['SSN'],"BirthPlace"=>$_POST['BirthPlace'],"DOB"=>$_POST['DOB'],"Email"=>$_POST['Email'],"MaritalStatus"=>$_POST['MaritalStatus']);
    print $personaldetails['MaidenName']; // This is how you would reference the array later
?>
```

Comment: Why use an additional array? How is this better than using `$_POST` directly?

Comment: Because that is the answer to the question he asked, not my biased opinion if it is good to code that way.

Comment: Crap I really like this option!  Then I could just append to it on more lines... thank you!

Comment: I still don't see how this helps. The OP wanted to declare individual variables, his data was already in an array which you have duplicated (minus the copy on write mechanism, that is).

Comment: Glad it helped you out. As stated above, a lot of people would recommend not using this method - but if using this means it's easier to work for your own personal coding style then hopefully it will save you time down the track.

Comment: RainFromHeaven - the OP just wanted to have them on the same line. It's probably easier for him to read it that way.

Comment: RainFromHeaven, ya I was just wanting to save space...this form is really terrible with over probably over 100 fields and I was just trying to save space in the script.  Its already going to be a nightmare when I get to the $stmt->bind_param(' part ... gosh I need to just find a different solution

Comment: @toddv - that's where this array can come in handy.  If you structure it properly, you could iterate over it to use to put information into your bind_param...

Comment: Oh JOY! cale_b... you're right!  I could probably just do a stmt->bind_param per iteration!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a `foreach` on the `$_POST`.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value; // mention the double $ sign. It wil create variable variable names
}
```

See http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m7r-gyw for a working example.